# React Bootstrap Accordion Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am struggling with my first bootstrap code.

I want to add an Accordion using react-bootstrap code from [here](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/accordion/#basic-example).

I think I also already have imported the correct library.

But I still have this error:
*"Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports."*

Here is my code if anyone can help, thanks a lot ^^
Hugo

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Accordion } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export class Maturite extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
                  <div style={{marginTop: '150px'}}></div>

                  {/* This is the 1st method from react bootstrap for an Accordion which is NOT working for me  */}
                  <Accordion>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
                        <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                    </Accordion>

                    {/* This is a 2nd method for an Accordion which is working for me  */}
                    <Accordion>
                      <Card>
                          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
                              TAB 1
                          </Accordion.Toggle>

                          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                              <Card.Body>This is first tab body</Card.Body>
                          </Accordion.Collapse>
                      </Card>

                      <Card>
                          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="1">
                              TAB 2
                          </Accordion.Toggle>

                          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                              <Card.Body>This is second tab body</Card.Body>
                          </Accordion.Collapse>
                      </Card>
                  </Accordion>
              </div>
      );
  }
}

export default Maturite;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Accordion } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export class Maturite extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
                  <div style={{marginTop: '150px'}}></div>

                  {/* This is the 1st method from react bootstrap for an Accordion which is NOT working for me  */}
                  <Accordion>
                    <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
                        <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
                        <Accordion.Body>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        </Accordion.Body>
                    </Accordion.Item>
                    </Accordion>

                    {/* This is a 2nd method for an Accordion which is working for me  */}
                    <Accordion>
                      <Card>
                          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="0">
                              TAB 1
                          </Accordion.Toggle>

                          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                              <Card.Body>This is first tab body</Card.Body>
                          </Accordion.Collapse>
                      </Card>

                      <Card>
                          <Accordion.Toggle as={Card.Header} eventKey="1">
                              TAB 2
                          </Accordion.Toggle>

                          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                              <Card.Body>This is second tab body</Card.Body>
                          </Accordion.Collapse>
                      </Card>
                  </Accordion>
              </div>
      );
  }
}

export default Maturite;
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this same issue with Accordion in react boostrap. It's weird because other components import and work fine, seems to hit some snags here. Will let you know if I find solution.

Comment: do you experience this error if you try and import in any other components from react-bootstrap library? For me, other components still work fine -- but this one gives me this same error. I did drop a message on their [discord channel](https://discord.gg/AKfs9vpvRW) -- will keep you posted if anything comes of it, or if I figure out what I'm doing wrong ;P

Comment: npm install react-bootstrap@next bootstrap@5.1.0 run this command

Answer (score 5):

What version of Bootstrap are you importing?

The layout of the  component that you're using that doesn't work (using Accordion.Header / .Body) is for the latest beta version of bootstrap ( Bootstrap 5.0 / v2.0.0-beta.4 ). If you're using Bootstrap 4.0 (v1.6.1) then the component has a different format, using Cards (the kind that's working for you).

Comment: Thanks! Forgot to switch my documentation to 4.0.